# How Can i get only this text? Without " DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> "

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lWya.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnZrE.png)

``
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return GestureDetector(
child: Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(automaticallyImplyLeading: false),
backgroundColor: Colors.black,
body: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('History').doc(userId).snapshots(),
builder: (context, snapshot) {
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
final DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>? getDocument = snapshot.data;
final Map<String, dynamic>? map = getDocument?.data();
var setList = map!['userchat'];
return ListView.builder(
itemCount: setList.length,
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
final get = setList[index];
print(get);
return const Text('data');
},
);
}
return const Text('data');
},
),
),
);
}

``

Comment: Please edit the question to be more clear what you are trying to accomplish and specifically you are stuck on.  I see that you have a document with n field called userchat that contains an array of references, but it's not clear what you intend to do with those references.

Comment: your snippet might be ok, try `return Text('data ${setList[index]}');` but as you've printed it is referring to the docRef, not sure. why

Answer (score 0):

For getting the required text, i.e., the text in index = 3, you can use a conditional check in *itemBuilder*.

```
if(index==3){
  final get = setList[index];
  print(get);
  return const Text('data');
}else{
  return const SizedBox.shrink();
}
```

**SizedBox.shrink()** helps in avoiding to return a null value, but in turn returns a widget which doesn't show up, or simply nothing.
You can use it if you want, or can go with **Text('data')**.